# Use of the bibliography style IEEEtran.bst yields hyphenation warning

Tags: miktex, hyphenation, ieeetran, english

This bibliography style does not want to use Babel hyphenation patterns, but it should generate its own for the English language.
On my current computer I am using Miktex 2.9 and I added all English languages via the Settings window (as an admin).
However I still get a lot of copies of the following warning (two per reference using the language field):

```
** WARNING: IEEEtran.bst: No hyphenation pattern has been
** loaded for the language `en'. Using the pattern for
** the default language instead.
```

I assume the default language is English as well, so I don't understand why these messages pop up. Does anyone have an idea what I can do to avoid these warnings?

a MWE:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\cite{laroussi_low_2005} 
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}               
\bibliography{bib1}
\end{document}
```

with bib1:

```
@article{laroussi_low_2005,
    title = {Low {Temperature} {Plasma}-{Based} {Sterilization}: {Overview} and {State}-of-the-{Art}},
    volume = {2},
    issn = {1612-8850, 1612-8869},
    shorttitle = {Low {Temperature} {Plasma}-{Based} {Sterilization}},
    url = {http://doi.wiley.com/10.1002/ppap.200400078},
    doi = {10.1002/ppap.200400078},
    language = {en},
    number = {5},
    urldate = {2016-02-01},
    journal = {Plasma Processes and Polymers},
    author = {Laroussi, Mounir},
    month = jun,
    year = {2005},
    pages = {391--400},
    file = {Laroussi - 2005 - Low Temperature Plasma-Based Sterilization Overvi.pdf:files/236/Laroussi - 2005 - Low Temperature Plasma-Based Sterilization Overvi.pdf:application/pdf}
}
```

Comment: Can you please add a minimal example?

Comment: I guess you need `\usepackage[english]{babel}`?

Comment: You are using `language=en`. You need `language=english`. See documentation of IEEtran *However, the names given in the
language field must follow Babel’s convention for the names
of the hyphenation patterns.*

Comment: Thanks! So the problem seems to originate from the exportation (I use Zotero) of the citation...

Comment: @MarcoDaniel ; `language=english` doesn't seem to work either and gives the same warning.

Comment: @ksyrium: When I change your entry by using `language = {english},` I am getting no warning.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Unfortunately I only don't get the warning if I remove the language field...

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the the comments the value `language` needs a key in form of `babel` is using it. The documentation of [`IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO_pdf`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex) says:

> *However, the names given in the language field must follow Babel’s
>   convention for the names of the hyphenation patterns.*

Using this convention your example should look like

```
% TEX TS-program = arara
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bib1.bib}
    @article{laroussi_low_2005,
        title = {Low {Temperature} {Plasma}-{Based} {Sterilization}: {Overview} and {State}-of-the-{Art}},
        volume = {2},
        issn = {1612-8850, 1612-8869},
        shorttitle = {Low {Temperature} {Plasma}-{Based} {Sterilization}},
        url = {http://doi.wiley.com/10.1002/ppap.200400078},
        doi = {10.1002/ppap.200400078},
        language = {english},
        number = {5},
        urldate = {2016-02-01},
        journal = {Plasma Processes and Polymers},
        author = {Laroussi, Mounir},
        month = jun,
        year = {2005},
        pages = {391--400},
        file = {Laroussi - 2005 - Low Temperature Plasma-Based Sterilization Overvi.pdf:files/236/Laroussi - 2005 - Low Temperature Plasma-Based Sterilization Overvi.pdf:application/pdf}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\cite{laroussi_low_2005} 
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}               
\bibliography{bib1}
\end{document}
```

The log-file doesn't have any warnings:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.2.25)  22 MAR 2017 12:34
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filecontents/filecontents.sty
Package: filecontents 2011/10/08 v1.3 Create an external file from within a LaT
eX document
)

LaTeX Warning: Overwriting file `./bib1.bib'.

\openout15 = `bib1.bib'.


LaTeX Warning: Tab has been converted to Blank Space.


(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/IEEEtran/IEEEtran.cls
Document Class: IEEEtran 2015/08/26 V1.8b by Michael Shell
-- See the "IEEEtran_HOWTO" manual for usage information.
-- http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenA=\dimen102
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenB=\dimen103
\@IEEEtrantmpdimenC=\dimen104
\@IEEEtrantmpcountA=\count79
\@IEEEtrantmpcountB=\count80
\@IEEEtrantmpcountC=\count81
\@IEEEtrantmptoksA=\toks14
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+ptm on input line 503.

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ptm.fd
File: ot1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
)
-- Using 8.5in x 11in (letter) paper.
-- Using PDF output.
\@IEEEnormalsizeunitybaselineskip=\dimen105
-- This is a 10 point document.
\CLASSINFOnormalsizebaselineskip=\dimen106
\CLASSINFOnormalsizeunitybaselineskip=\dimen107
\IEEEnormaljot=\dimen108
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <5> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <5> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <7> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <7> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <8> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <8> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <9> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <9> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <11> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <11> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <12> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <17> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <17> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <20> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <20> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <24> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 1090.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/it' in size <24> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/it' tried instead on input line 1090.

\IEEEquantizedlength=\dimen109
\IEEEquantizedlengthdiff=\dimen110
\IEEEquantizedtextheightdiff=\dimen111
\IEEEilabelindentA=\dimen112
\IEEEilabelindentB=\dimen113
\IEEEilabelindent=\dimen114
\IEEEelabelindent=\dimen115
\IEEEdlabelindent=\dimen116
\IEEElabelindent=\dimen117
\IEEEiednormlabelsep=\dimen118
\IEEEiedmathlabelsep=\dimen119
\IEEEiedtopsep=\skip41
\c@section=\count82
\c@subsection=\count83
\c@subsubsection=\count84
\c@paragraph=\count85
\c@IEEEsubequation=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip42
\belowcaptionskip=\skip43
\c@figure=\count87
\c@table=\count88
\@IEEEeqnnumcols=\count89
\@IEEEeqncolcnt=\count90
\@IEEEsubeqnnumrollback=\count91
\@IEEEquantizeheightA=\dimen120
\@IEEEquantizeheightB=\dimen121
\@IEEEquantizeheightC=\dimen122
\@IEEEquantizeprevdepth=\dimen123
\@IEEEquantizemultiple=\count92
\@IEEEquantizeboxA=\box26
\@IEEEtmpitemindent=\dimen124
\IEEEPARstartletwidth=\dimen125
\c@IEEEbiography=\count93
\@IEEEtranrubishbin=\box27
) (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
) (./test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 29.

-- Lines per column: 58 (exact).
(./test.bbl
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 30.
) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}


] (./test.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1141 strings out of 493013
 20576 string characters out of 6133343
 73491 words of memory out of 5000000
 4742 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 31549 words of font info for 65 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 26i,5n,19p,215b,337s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
{/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc
}</usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmr8a.pfb></usr/loc
al/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmri8a.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 23783 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 17 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 11 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```